# No table created after running Create Table query

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am new to SQL and learning the basics of MySQL, using MySQL Workbench. After running this query, which is supposed to create a new table, I don't see any table created. I also get this message in the output window: `0 row(s) affected`.

```
CREATE TABLE SpecialProducts
(
    prod_id CHAR(10)            NOT NULL,
    vend_id CHAR(10)            NOT NULL,
    prod_name CHAR(254)         NOT NULL,
    prod_price DECIMAL(8,2)     NOT NULL,
    prod_desc TEXT(1000)        NULL
);
```

Comment: have you checked your database schema ?? right click on your database and set as default schema.......may be your table have been created in public schema

Comment: click refresh icon in mysql workbench

Comment: As an aside, one of the basics is that EVERY table in an RDBMS has a PRIMARY KEY. (And CHAR(254) is extraordinarily unlikely!)

Comment: just type use database your_database_name; then type show tables;

Answer (score 1):

set your database as default schema like below:

1. select your databse from left bar in mysql workbench
2. right click on your db name and set as default schema

run below query to find your table

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='test'

select * from information_schema.tables
```